# How to set Now SMS as default SMS app?

Tags: sms, settings, default-applications

I have Nexus 7 2013 LTE with Android 4.4.2. I want to set Now SMS as the default SMS app but I have not been successful. After choosing it as the default, the popup is still shown next time I start Now SMS!

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What are the other options on this pop-up?

Comment: It shows a popup "Now SMS needs to be default sms app to work properly" with 2 options: cancel and ok

Comment: I tried Mighttext also but it couldnt send a sms to check my balance 3G!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Settings`, and under the "Wireless & Networks" section tap `More...`.  There should be an option called `Default SMS app`.  Tap it, and select the "Now SMS" app.  You should be all set now.

*[Edit]:*
Apparently, Google deliberately [disabled](http://8s.ms/sms-disabled-nexus-tablets-kitkat) the SMS functionality on cell-enabled Nexus 7 tabs (both 2012 3G and 2013 LTE tablets are impacted) with the 4.4 update. The recommended solution is to flash a [custom ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=47757063) that re-enables the setting.  Keep in mind that this will require unlocking the bootloader, which may void the warranty.

Comment: I tried that so far but the option is not there. It seems that something is missing when i update to 4.4.2

Comment: Is the "Default SMS app" option not there, or is "Now SMS" missing from the selection list?

Comment: Sorry,i mean that "Default SMS app" is missing

Comment: See the update.